# How to compile multiple Java files in an array

Tags: java

```
static String[] filesToCompile = new String[]{"Player", "OOJavaBootcamp"};
```

I want to compile both of this Java files in the array using the code below but it compiles just the Player object in the array.

```
 static String[] filesToCompile = new String[]{"Player", "OOJavaBootcamp"};
//Compile the student src file 
     System.out.println("\nCompiling tests file");
     Path destinationCompiledClassFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\aookpidi\\Desktop\\STUDEN~1\\SOFT22~1.2-6\\ALECCA~1\\OOJAVA~1\\build\\classes");
    Path classPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\aookpidi\\Desktop\\STUDEN~1\\SOFT22~1.2- 6\\ALECCA~1\\OOJAVA~1\\build\\classes\\OOJavaBootcamp\\");
    Path javaFileToCompile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\aookpidi\\Desktop\\STUDEN~1\\SOFT22~1.2-6\\ALECCA~1\\OOJAVA~1\\src\\OOJavaBootcamp\\");
    Path submissionPathString = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\aookpidi\\Desktop\\outputFiles");
    String compilerOutputFileName = "compilerOutput.txt";

    for (String fileToCompile : filesToCompile) {
        String compileCommand = "cmd /c javac -d \"" + destinationCompiledClassFile
                + "\" -cp \"" + classPath
                + "\" \"" + javaFileToCompile + "/"
                + fileToCompile + ".java\" >> \""
                + submissionPathString + "\\"
                + compilerOutputFileName + "\" 2>&1";

        System.out.println("Compile student source command: "
                + compileCommand);
```

Here is the console output:

```
         Compiling tests file
   Compile student source command: cmd /c javac -d "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\build\classes" -cp "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\build\classes\OOJavaBootcamp" "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp/Player.java" >> "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\outputFiles\compilerOutput.txt" 2>&1
   Compile student source command: cmd /c javac -d "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\build\classes" -cp "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\build\classes\OOJavaBootcamp" "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp/OOJavaBootcamp.java" >> "C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\outputFiles\compilerOutput.txt" 2>&1
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

The compiler output looks like this:

```
   C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter");
    ^
   symbol:   class Player
   location: class OOJavaBootcamp
    C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-  6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter");
                    ^
   symbol:   class Player
   location: class OOJavaBootcamp
   C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    Player p2 = new Player("Paul");
    ^
    symbol:   class Player
    location: class OOJavaBootcamp
    C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    Player p2 = new Player("Paul");
                    ^
    symbol:   class Player
   location: class OOJavaBootcamp
   C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    Player m = new Player("Mary");
    ^
    symbol:   class Player
    location: class OOJavaBootcamp
    C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    Player m = new Player("Mary");
                   ^
    symbol:   class Player
    location: class OOJavaBootcamp
    C:\Users\aookpidi\Desktop\STUDEN~1\SOFT22~1.2-6\ALECCA~1\OOJAVA~1\src\OOJavaBootcamp\OOJavaBootcamp.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    Player.printAllPlayers();
    ^
   symbol:   variable Player
   location: class OOJavaBootcamp
   7 errors
```

OOJavaBootcamp File contains this:

```
         public class OOJavaBootcamp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Player p1 = new Player("Peter");
    Player p2 = new Player("Paul");
    p2.setAge(18);
    Player m = new Player("Mary");
    m.setAge(30);
    Player.printAllPlayers();
}
```

}

Please what am I doing wrong? I am a novice programmer.
Thanks

Comment: what does OOJavaBootcamp.java look like?

Comment: @Ryan Please see my last edit

Comment: Please see [this post](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue180.html) and [this follow-up](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue181.html) for an example of dynamic compilation.